# Centos - my Centos 5 (hosted asterisk) always have a large CPU usage process

Tags: centos, asterisk, freepbx

i have a Centos 5 server which hosted asterisk 13.
server works fine last week but now top command always show me a process with large amount of CPU usage. when i kill the process a few second later another command with large CPU usage started. many times processes command is ".syslog" but have other command like "qjennjifes", "vnvebynufu" and another unknown commands like that.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server/218011#218011

Answer (score 0):

1) Check you have firewall and fail2ban recomended settings

2) Check you have no DoS/DDoS by "sip show channels"

3) Check your system not hacked/no broken soft on your host.

Comment: thank you, .syslog command usage fixed by blocking ddos attackers ip, but commands like "qjennjifes", "vnvebynufu" and ... is still have high cpu usage. after kill, another command runed.

Comment: Only one correct fix can be done : copy all voip config and stats to other host, reinstall all, restore from backup and NOT FORGET put firewall(better if firewall all except providers and clients).